# NIP-07 window.nostr is undefined. I tried window.webln and it works just not window.nostr

Tags: typescript, next.js

```
const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    try{
      // @ts-ignore
      var pubkey = await nostr.getPublicKey();
      alert(pubkey)
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Nostr extension not installed")
    }
  }
```

I am using NextJS and I have put this code snippet in my index.tsx file and the window does not recognize that I have alby installed and therefore does not prompt the user for their publickey. I started with this code in a page file and added a global type for window.nostr.

global.ts

```
import { EventTemplate, Event } from "nostr-tools";

declare global {
    interface Window {
     nostr: Nostr;
   }
}

type Nostr = {
   getPublicKey() : Promise<string>;
   signEvent(event: EventTemplate) : Promise<Event>;
};
```

The problem with just using lightning (window.webln) is that when I use the getInfo function the pubkey is undefined and I am trying to use this for user logins. I have tried a lot, putting the global.ts file in different places, but I don't know why the NIP-07 for nostr is not working for me. I cloned other repositories where it was confirmed to work and it still didn't work on my system. I am on a macbook air m1.

Comment: Shouldn't it be window.nostr.getPublicKey()?